# While using menu script, its only float left side. how can i put that center of DIV

Tags: html, css, menu, html-lists, center

I found this script online, but while using this its only float left side. i want this on center of DIV (id="menuback").

tried following but not working...

- margin-left:auto;
- margin-right:auto;
- text-align:center;

```css
ul {
 list-style-type:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 position: absolute;
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
 display:inline-block;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 1px;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
 display:block;
 min-width:140px;
 height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 50px;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 background: #2f3036;
 text-decoration: none;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
 background: #19c589;
}

/*Style for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a {
 background: #f3f3f3;
 color: #2f3036;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a:hover {
 background: #19c589;
 color: #fff;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
li ul {
 display: none;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
li ul li {
 display: block;
 float: none;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
 width: auto;
 min-width: 100px;
 padding: 0 20px;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
 display: block;
}

/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 background: #19c589;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px 0;
 display: none;
}

/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
    display: block;
}


/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
 /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
 ul {
  position: static;
  display: none;
 }
 /*Create vertical spacing*/
 li {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
 }
 /*Make all menu links full width*/
 ul li, li a {
  width: 100%;
 }
 /*Display 'show menu' link*/
 .show-menu {
  display:block;
 }
}
```

```html
<div id="menuback" style="text-align:center"> 
 <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
 <ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">menu2</a>
   <ul class="hidden">
    <li><a href="#">sub1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub2</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">menu3</a>
   <ul class="hidden">
    <li><a href="#">sub1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub3</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">menu4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">menu5</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a specific width to your menu e.g 400px and set its margin:0 auto;

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that your `ul#menu` has `position: absolute` so it don't follow the flow of the document, so remove `position: absolute` an set `display: inline-block`

like this:

```css
ul {
 list-style-type:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 /*position: absolute;*/ /*removed*/
    display: inline-block; /*added*/
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
 display:inline-block;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 1px;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
 display:block;
 min-width:140px;
 height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 50px;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 background: #2f3036;
 text-decoration: none;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
 background: #19c589;
}

/*Style for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a {
 background: #f3f3f3;
 color: #2f3036;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a:hover {
 background: #19c589;
 color: #fff;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
li ul {
 display: none;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
li ul li {
 display: block;
 float: none;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
 width: auto;
 min-width: 100px;
 padding: 0 20px;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
 display: block;
}

/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 background: #19c589;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px 0;
 display: none;
}

/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
 /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
 ul {
  position: static;
  display: none;
 }
 /*Create vertical spacing*/
 li {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
 }
 /*Make all menu links full width*/
 ul li, li a {
  width: 100%;
 }
 /*Display 'show menu' link*/
 .show-menu {
  display:block;
 }
    /*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
    input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ #menu{
      display: block; /*setting block at low resolution*/
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="menuback" style="text-align:center"> 
 <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
 <ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">menu2</a>
   <ul class="hidden">
    <li><a href="#">sub1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub2</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">menu3</a>
   <ul class="hidden">
    <li><a href="#">sub1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub3</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">menu4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">menu5</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

If you want the menu has `position: absolute` for some reason add a wrapper that has the position

Like this:

```css
.menu-wrapper{          /*added*/
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}

ul {
 list-style-type:none;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 /*position: absolute;*/ /*removed*/
    display: inline-block; /*added*/
}

/*Create a horizontal list with spacing*/
li {
 display:inline-block;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 1px;
}

/*Style for menu links*/
li a {
 display:block;
 min-width:140px;
 height: 50px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 50px;
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 color: #fff;
 background: #2f3036;
 text-decoration: none;
}

/*Hover state for top level links*/
li:hover a {
 background: #19c589;
}

/*Style for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a {
 background: #f3f3f3;
 color: #2f3036;
 height: 40px;
 line-height: 40px;
}

/*Hover state for dropdown links*/
li:hover ul a:hover {
 background: #19c589;
 color: #fff;
}

/*Hide dropdown links until they are needed*/
li ul {
 display: none;
}

/*Make dropdown links vertical*/
li ul li {
 display: block;
 float: none;
}

/*Prevent text wrapping*/
li ul li a {
 width: auto;
 min-width: 100px;
 padding: 0 20px;
}

/*Display the dropdown on hover*/
ul li a:hover + .hidden, .hidden:hover {
 display: block;
}

/*Style 'show menu' label button and hide it by default*/
.show-menu {
 font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #fff;
 background: #19c589;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 10px 0;
 display: none;
}

/*Hide checkbox*/
input[type=checkbox]{
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}


/*Responsive Styles*/

@media screen and (max-width : 760px){
 /*Make dropdown links appear inline*/
 .menu-wrapper {
  position: static;
  display: none;
 }
 /*Create vertical spacing*/
 li {
  margin-bottom: 1px;
 }
 /*Make all menu links full width*/
 ul li, li a {
  width: 100%;
 }
    ul{
      display: block;
    }
 /*Display 'show menu' link*/
 .show-menu {
  display:block;
 }
  /*Show menu when invisible checkbox is checked*/
    input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ .menu-wrapper{  /*added the .menu-wrapper selector*/
       display: block;   /*setting block at low resolution*/
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="menuback" style="text-align:center"> 
 <label for="show-menu" class="show-menu">Show Menu</label>
 <input type="checkbox" id="show-menu" role="button">
  
    <div class="menu-wrapper"> <!--added awrapper-->
 <ul id="menu">
  <li><a href="#">menu1</a></li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">menu2</a>
   <ul class="hidden">
    <li><a href="#">sub1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub2</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
   <a href="#">menu3</a>
   <ul class="hidden">
    <li><a href="#">sub1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub3</a></li>
   </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">menu4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">menu5</a></li>
 </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your support, but i am getting error wile using responsive version.its not working ... dropdown nav causing html content to move ...

Comment: @rishp I update both example to fix the error wile using responsive version, I added comments to show what I change.

Answer (score 0):

add this CSS to `ul`

```
ul {
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,0);
}
```